# Android Wear Message Listener

Tags: java, android, android-intent, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I need some help I have Android Wear with message api working but I'm stuck sending some commands this is my listener.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.WearableListenerService;
public class ListenerServiceFromWear extends WearableListenerService {
    private static final String HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH = "/hello-world-wear" ;
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH)) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            //        "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class) ;
            // startIntent.putExtra("name",0);
            startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) ;
            startActivity(startIntent) ;

        }
        else {
            // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call the methods of my phone on my code I can initialize the phone class but after that I can't call more methods like : on | off. How do I call methods of the MainActivity class?

I also tried killing the process but the Wear device must close and reopen to respond after that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this ;) best thing ever found for Wear

https://github.com/Mariuxtheone/Teleport